# Random code of colors(jawa.awt) without duplicates

Tags: java, random

So i'm trying to make a random code that uses jawa.awt.colors. I want the code not be able to have duplicates, like it does atm. 
The code needs to hold 4 colors.

I found that you can use java.util.Collections.shuffle(), but this unfortunately doesn't work with with java.awt colors and i need  to use the java.awt.colors later in my code so i can't just use something else.

Is there any other way?

Below is my code that does make duplicates:

```
public class SecretCombination {

public int codeLength = 4;

public Random random = new Random();

public Color[] PossibleColors = {Color.RED, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.yellow, Color.PINK,Color.BLACK};

public Color[] SecretColorCombi = new Color[codeLength];


public SecretCombination() {
    for (int i = 0; i < codeLength; i++) {
        SecretColorCombi[i] = PossibleColors[random.nextInt(PossibleColors.length)];
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `I found that you can use java.util.Collections.shuffle(), but this unfortunately doesn't work with with java.awt colors` - sure it does. Post your code showing how you used the method.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using `Collections.shuffle` method you can achieve it using following method,

```
public static Color[] possibleColors = { Color.RED, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.yellow, Color.PINK, Color.BLACK };
public static List<Color> colorList = Arrays.asList(possibleColors);

public static List<Color> getRandomColorList() {
    Collections.shuffle(colorList);
    return colorList.subList(0, 4);
}
```

**As an alternate, you can also try using following solution and see how to avoid picking duplicate Color object.**

As you want to pick the colors randomly but unique, change the strategy of picking elements randomly from a fixed array. Because your random number out of six elements can repeat. To make it repeat immune, have your colors stored in a list rather than an array. You still pick the elements randomly from list, but you remove the color that gets picked once from the list, this way a color that has been picked will never be repeated again, as it is no longer there in the list.

Here is an updated code of your version for my strategy above,

```
public class SecretCombination {

    public int codeLength = 4;

    public Random random = new Random();

    public Color[] PossibleColors = { Color.RED, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.yellow, Color.PINK, Color.BLACK };
    public List<Color> colorList = new ArrayList<Color>(Arrays.asList(PossibleColors));

    public Color[] SecretColorCombi = new Color[codeLength];

    public SecretCombination() {
        for (int i = 0; i < codeLength; i++) {
            int randIndex = random.nextInt(colorList.size());
            Color randColor = colorList.remove(randIndex);
            System.out.println("Length: " + colorList.size() + ", Color Picked: " + randColor);
            SecretColorCombi[i] = randColor;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SecretCombination secretCombination = new SecretCombination();
        Stream.of(secretCombination.SecretColorCombi).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Finally you can print the colors in the main method to verify that they never repeat.

Here is one of the sample output for the program where you can see the colors are not repeated and the list of colors shrinks by one as it loops.

```
Length: 5, Color Picked: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=175,b=175]
Length: 4, Color Picked: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
Length: 3, Color Picked: java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255]
Length: 2, Color Picked: java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=175,b=175]
java.awt.Color[r=255,g=0,b=0]
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255]
java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=0]
```

Comment: (1-) Why reinvent the wheel when Collections.shuffle(...) will work?

Comment: Yes `Collections.shuffle` surely works but my answer was for this statement from OP `Is there any other way?` Moreover, my answer was also to show how OP could correct his strategy, which shouldn't be a bad thing that really deserved a downvote. Downvoting an incorrect answer is understandable but downvoting an alternate approach doesn't seem fine. With my answer OP at least got some insight, that in case he has to implement something similar, he knows how to do it. I've also added a solution using shuffle method.

Comment: He asked for another way because he couldn't get Collections.shuffle() to work. The problem is NOT with Collections.shuffle(). The problem is with the OP's code. The OP should learn to read the API and use existing methods. If there is a problem we should help him understand the usage of the method. The down vote was to discourage anybody else from using the solution when there is a simple one line solution already available in the API. People always seem to pay more attention to a down vote then just a comment.